# Finding $\int \ln\ln x\ dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Find $\int \ln\ln x\,\mathrm dx$.

I tried$$\int \ln\ln x\,\mathrm dx=x\ln\ln x -\int \frac{1}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx\\=x\ln x\ln x-\sqrt{x}{\ln x}-\int \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
It seems more and more difficult. And I tried substitution, i.e. substituting the $\ln \ln x$ to $t$, then $=\int t\ e^{e^t}e^t\,\mathrm dt$ and then I can not integral it.

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Comment: There is no simple expression for your integral.  Moreover, the first line of analysis appears incorrect: the last term should be $ \int 1 / ln x dx $

Comment: Did you mean it can not be represented as the elementary function?@GerryMyerson

Comment: Yes, red, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int\ln\ln(x)dx=x\ln\ln(x)-\int\frac{dx}{\ln x}=x\ln\ln(x)-\text{Li}(x)+c $$

Comment: Could you provide more details abour what  Li(x) is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: Thank you! I got it.